# Prove that $\sum{a^{2}bc}=\binom{n+3}{6}+\binom{n+2}{6}$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

**Question**

We define $S$ as the set of positive integer triplets $(a,b,c)$ such that $a+b+c=n$. I want to prove that the following expression is correct:

$$
\sum_{S}{a^{2}bc}=\binom{n+3}{6}+\binom{n+2}{6}
$$

**My Solution**

*Left Hand Side*

Say that there is a line of $n$ balls. We color the first $a$ balls red, the next $b$ balls green, and the rest blue. We then choose two red balls randomly with replacement, choose one green ball randomly, and choose one blue ball randomly. The number of possibilities is given by $\sum_{S}{a^{2}bc}$

*Right Hand Side*

If the same red ball is chosen twice;

$$
\begin{align}
x_{1}&\text{ red balls lie on the left of the chosen red ball}\\
x_{2}&\text{ red balls lie on the right of the chosen red ball}\\
x_{3}&\text{ green balls lie on the left of the chosen green ball}\\
x_{4}&\text{ green balls lie on the right of the chosen green ball}\\
x_{5}&\text{ blue balls lie on the left of the chosen blue ball}\\
x_{6}&\text{ blue balls lie on the right of the chosen blue ball}
\end{align}
$$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^{6}{x_{i}=n-3}$, using stars and bars we get $\binom{n+2}{5}$ possibilities.

If different red balls are chosen, the approach is the same but we also need to count the number of red balls between the two chosen red ball and multiply by two because either red ball can be chosen first. This give us $2\binom{n+2}{6}$ possibilities.

Since I counted the same possibilities, then the expressions must be equal:

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{S}{a^{2}bc}&=2\binom{n+2}{6}+\binom{n+2}{5}\\
\\
&=\binom{n+3}{6}+\binom{n+2}{6}
\end{align}
$$

I’d like to know if my solution is correct and if there is alternative solution or discussion.

Comment: Balls of same colour are different form each other ?

Comment: @Sukhoi234 yes, in this case they are distinguishable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative solution: let us consider the following generating functions (power series with $\rho=1$):

$$ A(x)=\sum_{a\geq 1}a^2 x^a,\qquad B(x)=\sum_{b\geq 1} b x^b,\qquad C(x) = \sum_{c\geq 1} c x^c. $$
The sum $\sum a^2 bc$ over the triples of positive integers such that $a+b+c=n$ is exactly the coefficient of $x^n$ in $A(x)B(x)C(x)$. By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) we have (formally, pointwise for any $x\in(-1,1)$ and uniformly over the compact subsets of $(-1,1)$)
$$ B(x)=C(x)=\frac{x}{(1-x)^2},\qquad A(x)=\frac{x(1+x)}{(1-x)^3} $$
so
$$ \sum_{a+b+c=n}a^2 bc = [x^n]\frac{x^3+x^4}{(1-x)^7}=[x^{n-3}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^7}+[x^{n-4}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^7} $$
where, as usual, $[x^n]f(x)$ stands for the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin series of $f(x)$.
 Always by stars and bars we have
$$ \frac{1}{(1-x)^7}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+6}{6}x^n $$
so
$$ \sum_{a+b+c=n}a^2 b c = \binom{n+2}{6}+\binom{n+3}{6} $$
as wanted.

Comment: Wow, that is impressive!

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja: generating functions deserve to be studied. If you don't know it already, I suggest this great book: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html (Wilf's *Generatingfunctionology* can be freely downloaded from the linked page, I am not breaking any copyright law here). It improved my "math wizardry" by *a lot*.

Comment: Sure will do! I have seen many people use it before but I have not gotten the chance to learn it since I started working